# Can I pass list from one endpoint to another endpoint with looping in same file

Tags: karate

My use case is to hit endpoint 1 from my API which returns a list of jsons and take the id from each json list and hit endpoint 2 with that and later validate

Endpoint 1 get returns list of jsons like below:

```
[
{
"id": 123,
"name": "test1",
"value": "uk123"
},
{
"id": 143,
"name": "test2",
"value": "us143"
}...
]
```

My scenario is:

```
Scenario: test
Given path "\endpoint1"
When method get
Then status 200
* def res = response
Given path "\endpoint2"
And param {"id": pass-each-id-from-above-response-list-one-at-a-time}
When method get
Then status 200
Then match response.id = (use-above-passed-each-id-from-above-response-list-for-validation)
```

Is there a possibility for writing this workflow using karate?

Sorry for posting this again, as I mistakenly removed the post. I did go through your documentation about call method available, but I was unable to find something which does this as part of the same feature file and not calling it from an another feature file. So posting it again.
Sorry again for causing inconvenience, if I have missed anything.
I am learning this tool and this tool had helped me resolve many of my API testing requirements.

Thank you!

Comment: It was for a workflow scenario, where we have one API which returns all the IDs as a list and I need to iterate it as part of a workflow. Sorry if that's a stupid requirement. May be I will try to explore more. Thank you and sorry again for the bad question

Comment: It is not blocking me anyways, but just thought of asking if that's at all possible to call a scenario instead of a separate feature file

Comment: At times it is missed,since I am too learning this tool, sorry but will be more cautious in future before asking any simple doubt and will go through the entire doc/video thoroughly. Thanks for your prompt replies always.

Comment: @automation.ninja.08 when you have a solution with calling a feature file (which is modular and a good approach), why do you want to force the solution within a single feature file?

Comment: I totally agree, that it gives a modular approach, but just wanted to check if at all that's possible so thought of checking.

Comment: @automation.ninja.08 if you want to force it, you can have a Scenario for the first request and write the json list response in a json file. Next in a Scenario Outline, read the json file in the Examples to loop through the json list.

Comment: Thanks, I did the same for my implementation. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the link
https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features
It has tje example you can use